# Need help using Karaf's features-maven-plugin maven plugin... osgi

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

My goal is to create a features.xml for my multi-module maven project and gather all the required jars needed for the various features.  I need to resolve the bundle jars via file: rather than mvn:

I tried using the features:generate-features-xml goal.  First off, there is no documentation on what the format of the  property file should look like.  Second, it creates bundles that are all resolved by mvn:  E.g.

```
<feature name='spring-jms' version='3.1.0.RELEASE'>
  <bundle>mvn:org.springframework/spring-tx/3.1.0.RELEASE</bundle>
  <feature version='3.1.0.RELEASE'>spring-core</feature>
  <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.9</bundle>
  <bundle>mvn:org.springframework/spring-jms/3.1.0.RELEASE</bundle>
</feature>
```

My first question is Is there any way to access the bundles via file: rather than mvn: ?
E.g.

```
<bundle>file:some/path/spring-tx.jar</bundle>
```

or whatever.

Second question:  what is the best way to gather up all the required jar files?  I've been doing with the maven assembly plugin, but that seems suboptimal.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need file based resolution?

Comment: we're shipping this as a product.  no expectation that the end user will have access to maven repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the file format to address bundles in feature files but the maven feature plugin only supports maven resolution.

It is quite typical that the end user of your application does not have access to the internet. Still you can use maven resolution. There are two main options you have:

- Use the karaf features plugin to create a maven repo from a feature. You can then add this directory to the list of maven repos in org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg
- From karaf 2.3 on you can use kar files. A kar file is a zip of a maven repo and a pointer to a features file inside. You can put a kar file into the deploy folder of karaf and it will install the feature

The nice thing about this is that your feature files are always based on the maven ids of your artifacts. You only change the way youu deliver your jars. So in the case where you have internet or maven repo access you can simply work with the feature file (for example in development).